# Obj-C: Delegate property to an instance variable?

Tags: objective-c, properties

So, let's say I have an Obj-C class with an array as a property, something like this:

```
@interface Collection
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *items;
@end
```

So, let's assume that while I've got `items` as an `NSArray`, I define `push` and `pop` methods etc. that use temporary mutable arrays and then replace the items immutable array, so essentially my items property acts like a mutable array. Now, let's say I want to be able to get the number of items in an instance. I know I can make a method like so:

```
- (NSUInteger)getCount
{
  return self.items.count;
}
```

However, is there any way for me to create a `count` property that simply delegates to the `items` property instead?

If possible I'm interested in the Collection class behaving like an array in most ways, so I'd love for count to be accessible as a property on an instance like:

```
collection.count
```

...instead of...

```
[collection getCount]
```

...but I can't think of how to do that.

If that's not possible, what would the "normal Obj-C way" to do something like this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dot notation in objective-c is not restricted to properties declared with the `@property` syntax. If you declared a method `- (NSUInteger)count;` you can call it with `collection.count`. However doing so it likely to confuse other developers. Instead include both the `@property` declaration and implement the custom getter to define the behavior you want:

```
@property(readonly) NSUInteger count;

- (NSUInteger) count {
  ...
}
```

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW13

Alternately you could also specify the getter method to use in the property declaration (e.g. `@property(readonly, getter=getCount)` but there's no need to do so in this case.